# How to design the splash screen (the loader page) of the react app

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app

After building the project with `create-react-app`, and hosting it on a webserver, when you visit your website using your smartphone, and click on the ***"Add to home screen"*** button in the browser, a shortcut of your website (pwa?) gets created on your smartphone home screen,

When you open this shortcut, a loading page shows up, this loading page comes from the **"./public/manifest.json"** file which is in your React project,

The **manifest.json** file includes some options, such as changing the starter screen background color, and the title which shows down in the bottom, ex:

the following file results in the following output:

```json
{
  "short_name": "Catering",
  "name": "Catering and logistics",
  "icons": [
    {
      "src": "favicon.ico",
      "sizes": "100x100 64x64 32x32 24x24 16x16",
      "type": "image/x-icon"
    },
    {
      "src": "icon.png",
      "type": "image/png",
      "sizes": "100x100"
    }
  ],
  "start_url": ".",
  "display": "standalone",
  "theme_color": "#000000",
  "background_color": "orange"
}
```

[image]

You see, there aren't many options, I want to design something which looks as follows:

[image]

So in order to do so, I should be able to write some code,

for example some CSS, some Jsx or HTML or whatever.

How to do that? where I can write the code for this loader page? and what is its name?

Comment: Does this help? https://www.simicart.com/blog/pwa-splash-screen/

Comment: @vighnesh153, it's a useful tool, but it's not part of the solution